# Displaying configurable downtime messages on HTML page

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, json

We have created a login page with a banner to display application specific downtime messages. I was able to read the application details from a JSON file and render the messages on load of login page. We are planning to develop an interface to allow administrators to configure the application downtime messages.The details entered by the administrator would be added/updated to the JSON file.

Is it possible to update the JSON file from a web application such that the file gets updated on all the server nodes. We currently have 4 nodes for the application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm no expert but your best option would be from a shared database or all nodes would point to the same file on one central server. May i ask why wouldn't this message be in a database ?

Comment: This will be a frequently accessed login page. We wanted to avoid DB hit when the page is loaded.

Comment: If this data will not change frequently, caching that query is pretty simple and should not impact your server's resources. Also, your databse is already synched right ? But if this decision cannot changed, then sorry i have no answer, but there must be packages that allow syncing of physical files accross multiple nodejs instances